# How to affect only real EOL characters , NOT the "\n" in text

Tags: python, eol

I have a string similar to this:

> Lorem ipsum '\n' ipsum lorem
>
> And this is new paragraph.

I want to remove the EOL chars and these 2 paragraphs to become one line. BUT I dont want to affect the '\n' - which in this case is literally used (not as new line indicator).

If I just make:

```
var.replace('\n', '')
```

This will affect it as:

> "Lorem ipsum '' ipsum loremAnd this is new paragraph."

And I want it to be:

> "Lorem ipsum '\n' ipsum loremAnd this is new paragraph."

Comment: There is not difference between an "EOL character" and `"\n"`.  They are the same thing.  The two-character string consisting of a back slash and the character "n" (Python reperesentation: `"\\n"` or `u"\n"`) is something different, but it won't be repleaced by `var.replace('\n', '')`.

Comment: If the text literally contains `\n`, it works fine: http://ideone.com/23367

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = r'''
Lorem ipsum '\n' ipsum lorem

And this is new paragraph.
'''

print(s.replace('\n', ''))

->"Lorem ipsum '\n' ipsum loremAnd this is new paragraph."
```

Adding the 'r' when assigning the string to a variable tells python to interpret it as a raw string literal, meaning that it will see backslashes as literal backslashes and not as escape characters.

Comment: Hi , thank you for the fast reply.

Is it possible that Python 3.2 add automaticaly this r.

Because i just tryed something:
made txt file (under windows) and put there 3-4 paragraphs + random \n (literaly) inside them.

Then i opened the file (r mode) and replaced all EOL (.replace('\n', 'ENDoFLINE')). Then i save it again 

When i open the file , the EOL are gone and the literaly typed \n are not touched. Which works great for me , but i wanted to know why replace('\n', 'ENDofLINE') replaces only the actual EOL chars and not the \n